# How to access Managed memory simultaneously by CPU and GPU in compute capability 5.0?

Tags: cuda, gpu-managed-memory

Since simultaneous access to managed memory on devices of compute capability lower than 6.x is not possible [(CUDA Toolkit Documentation)](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-coherency-hd), is there a way to simulatneously access managed memory by CPU and GPU with compute capability 5.0 or any method that can make CPU access managed memory while GPU kernel is running.

Comment: There is no way for the GPU and CPU to simultaneously access managed memory on cc5.0.  The only memory resource that provides simultaneous access before Pascal GPUs is zero-copy (pinned) memory.

Comment: What is the difference between Unified and zero-copy memory? can zero-copy memory use single array to access from both CPU and GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to simulatneously access managed memory by CPU and GPU with compute capability 5.0

No.

> or any method that can make CPU access managed memory while GPU kernel is running.

Not on a compute capability 5.0 device.

You can have "simultaneous" CPU and GPU access to data using CUDA [zero-copy techniques](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#page-locked-host-memory).

A full tutorial on both Unified memory as well as Pinned/Mapped/Zero-copy memory is well beyond the scope of what I can write in an answer here.  Unified Memory has [its own section](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-unified-memory-programming-hd) in the programming guide.  Both of these topics are extensively covered here on the `cuda` tag on SO as well as many other places on the web.  **Any questions will likely be answerable with a google search.**

In a nutshell, zero-copy memory on 64-bit OS is accessed via a host pinning API such as `cudaHostAlloc()`.  The memory so allocated is host memory, and always remains there, but it is accessible to the GPU.  The access to this memory from GPU to host memory occurs across the PCIE bus, so it is much slower than normal global memory access.  The pointer returned by the allocation (on 64-bit OS) is usable in both host and device code.  You can study CUDA sample codes that use zero-copy techniques such as [`simpleZeroCopy`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simplezerocopy).

By contrast, ordinary unified memory (UM) is data that will be migrated to the processor that is using it.  In a pre-pascal UM regime, this migration is triggered by kernel calls and synchronizing operations.  Simultaneous access by host and device in this regime is not possible.  For pascal and beyond devices in a proper UM post-pascal regime (basically, 64-bit linux only, CUDA 8+), the data is migrated on-demand, even during kernel execution, thus allowing a limited form of "simultaneous" access.  Unified Memory has various behavior modes, and some of those will cause a unified memory allocation to "decay" into a pinned/zero-copy host allocation, under some circumstances.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I guess I have to buy a system with GPU having compute capability 6.0 or above since my project is strictly on Unified memory.